# Using git submodules via bitbucket pipelines

Tags: bash, git, bitbucket, git-submodules, bitbucket-pipelines

So I have a versioning script that I wanted to share across several of my repos. I decided to use submodules for this purpose–maybe not the brightest idea...

I am trying to call the versioning script from BB pipelines in this way:

```
image: python:3.6

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Development build - linting
        script:
          - git submodule init
          - bash versioning/version.sh
```

Unfortunately I get the following error message:
`bash: versioning/version.sh: No such file or directory`

However, when I run `echo "$(ls)"` I see that the folder versioning is present. I tried running echo `"$(cd versioning; ls)"`, but that didn't work for some reason...